# How to Install boinc at /home

Tags: kubuntu, custom-installer, boinc

I was wondering how can i install boinc at /home folder. I have an ssd for root and /home on a hdd. Since boinc does lot of write/read i would like to avoid installing it on my ssd (which i already did via muon). I have trim enabled and working but i would still like to get it on my hdd. Do i have to uninstall/reinstall boinc and if yes how do i install it at /home folder? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to install application files to your HDD - as any other program files they're very rarely written to. What you need to do is to make BOINC keep its data files on the SSD. From their website:

> **What the installer does**
>
> - Puts the BOINC binaries (boinc, boinccmd and boincmgr) in /usr/bin .
> - Creates a configuration directory /etc/boinc-client ...
> - Creates the working directory **/var/lib/boinc-client/** for BOINC data files and the slots and projects directories. Also creates links from this directory to the files in /etc/boinc-client

So what I would do is to install BOINC first, then move `/var/lib/boinc-client/` to somewhere on your SSD (taking care to keep permissions) and create a symlink at `/var/lib/boinc-client/` pointing to the new location

(alternatively you may check the configs in `/etc/boinc-client` and see if it's possible to change the data directory from there)

**UPDATE:** How to create a symlink:

1. make sure BOINC is not running
2. move the directory:

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/boinc-client /home/boinc-working-dir
   ```
3. create the symlink:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /home/boinc-working-dir /var/lib/boinc-client
   ```

Comment: Whats the point to move `/var/lib/boinc-client/`? Its already on my ssd. I also checked the cfg files but they dont have anything about data path. To sum up: all i need to do is copy the content of `/var/lib/boinc-client/` on a new location base on hdd and somehow point that out so the program knows where to search, right?  (Excuse me for being noobish :) )

Comment: You want to minimize the number of writes to your SSD, right? The only place boinc can write to is `/var/lib/boinc-client/`. You need to move that directory to HDD. The easiest way to do this is to MOVE it from where it is now to somewhere on HDD AND create a symlink where it was before, pointing to the new location. Then the program would think that it writes to `/var/lib/boinc-client` while in reality it'll be some other location on HDD.

Comment: I added some info on creating a symlink